# How I can use wolfram to solve 'x=atant, t=?'

Tags: equation-solving

x=atant, a is a constant, then t=?
How to use wolfram to solve this equation?

Comment: Does `Solve[x == a Tan[t], t]` work for you?

Comment: sorry, I use your code and press shift+enter but it just print "solve[x == a Tan[t], t]",maybe my Operation method is wrong, because I am a beginner....

Comment: Try replacing the s by an S in solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it in the follwoing way:

```
Solve[x == a Tan[t], {t}]
```

The result from the above code is:
$
\left.t\to \fbox{$\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+\pi  c_1\text{ if }c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$}\right\}
$

Comment: or ` t /. First@Solve[x == a Tan[t], t]`

Comment: emmm....Can you tell me how to learn wolfram? I think I should have more practice.

Comment: @appleMusic there are many resources available...have you tried looking at the official wolfram site? They have many different introductory methods to learn...

Comment: thanks, but the offical site have many advanced tips, may be it is hard for me...